# Autorefresh with OAuth2 Authentification in PowerBi's Data Gateway Connection

Tags: powerbi

When creating a connection with [PowerBi Virtual Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/vnet/overview) to an `Azure Storage Gen 2` I have the option to choose between SAS, AccountKey and OAuth2.

[image]

I want to go for OAuth2.

Assume I have a dataset in powerbi and select the connection (with OAuth2 authentication) and enable an auto-refresh, e.g. each hour: which OAuth2 credentials are used for accessing `Azure Storage Gen 2` when a auto-refresh is done?